# WFS Layer Not Display

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver, web-feature-service

I created WFS GeoJson layer from GeoServer ,I got this url'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/trail/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=trail:sbi_branch_data&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson' ,I got example from OL3 examples From that code ,I tried some code in OpenLayer3 ,but giving some error.please help me .Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WFS</title>
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.0/build/ol.js"></script>-->

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol.css" type="text/css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sample.css" type="text/css" />


    </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
     <script src="js/ol.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/trail/ows?service=WFS&'+
          'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=trail:sbi_branch_data&'+
          'maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
              'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
      });


      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
            width: 2
          })
        })
      });

      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
       // source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
         // imagerySet: 'Aerial',
        //  key: 'Your Bing Maps Key from http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ here'
      //  })
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [20.5937, 78.9629],
          maxZoom: 19,
          zoom: 12
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error:
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/geoserver/trail/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request…644126996,-13297.517049905844,22569.517044127,13455.442849905845,EPSG:4326. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: This is the cross domain scripting problem. You either have to enable CORS on geoserver or make a proxy class on your server to handle the requests to geoserver.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101679/same-origin-policy-problem-using-wfs-t-with-geoserver-openlayers-3

Comment: Thanks for help,you have any idea how ton enable jsonp from geoserver.

Comment: Anything wrong in this code .I enable CORS and JSONP but still i have error .please help me.

Comment: please anyone help to solve this problem.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,First I installed the Apache then modify the httpd.config file.I just put

`ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy /geoserver>
Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver`

ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver

this code in httpd.config at the end of file.
 and then enabled this from httpd.config

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Then all my html files i stored in ht-docs in Apache ,then runs all the wfs files.